# POST request to view function

Tags: python, django, post

I want to send POST request to view function. Now I am getting 500 error. I could not figure out where is the problem. The view function is receiving POST request but not returning any data.

**EDIT:** Now problem with 500 error solved. But how should I return form for editing object?

Template:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function editParticipant(event_id, row_id){
    var postdata = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
    }
    $.post( "/edit-participant-" + event_id + "/", postdata, function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

View:

```
def edit_participant(request, participant_id):
    participant = Participant.objects.get(pk=participant_id)
    form = RegisterToEvent(request.POST or None, instance = participant)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-%s' %2)
    data = {'form': form}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

URL:

```
url(r'^edit-participant-(?P<participant_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'event.views.edit_participant', name='edit_participant'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view doesn't return a response

```
def edit_participant(request, participant_id):
    return JsonResponse({'data':"Test"})
```

---

You should also turn on debug in the settings by setting `DEBUG` to true, it will tell you exactly what the error is, just remember to turn this off before production. You can also implement error logging.

---

There isn't anything about this function that needs to use ajax requests. If you want to keep the same page if the form isn't valid, then just return the form errors and do something with them

```
data = { 'errors': form.errors }
```

But this doesn't make much sense to me when you can just load the page again with a form and let django do it for you with its form rendering.

```
return render(request, 'yourhtml.html', {form: form})
```

Comment: I need to return form, can I still use JsonResponse?

Comment: @Rokas - What form? form data or the actual raw html that creates the html? either way its a yes, the data is a dictionary so put what you like in it

Comment: I want to return like this, but I am getting "is not JSON serializable"      `def edit_participant(request, participant_id):
 participant = Participant.objects.get(pk=participant_id)
 form = RegisterToEvent(request.POST or None, instance = participant)
 if form.is_valid():
  form.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-%s' %2)
 return JsonResponse({'form': form})`

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33993720/edit) button on your question to include new information. Why are you returning the form?..

Comment: @Rokas - I've updated my answer but really you should be creating another question if you have a follow up question